# Jquery UI Tabs with same height

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I want to use Jquery UI Tabs to make three tabs that all contain the same sized content area. The size of the content area seems dependent on the content. How do I force it so all three tabs have the same sized content area so that I can use a height of 100% for the content and they will just fill all available space?

Thanks!

Comment: What should determine the height? Do you have a specific height in mind? Do you want them all the same height as the tallest?

Comment: Basically I want a fixed height for the size of the tabs + tab content. So that all content areas are the same size. I plan to put a scrolling Grid inside each of the three tabs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a specific height in mind then you could just specify that height on the appropriate `.ui-tabs-panel`s. Given HTML like this:

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">One</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Three</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you could make all the panels 200px tall with:

```
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel {
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/SQu6K/

Comment: Thank you very much this got me really close. I updated the fiddler http://jsfiddle.net/SQu6K/16/ adding in the grid that I wanted to use in tab 1. Using your technique mostly works as you can see at the link. But it uses the non themed scroll bars. I want to use the scroller inside the grid so I tried setting the grids height (the table) to 100% but that does not do what I would expect. Is there a way to make it work with the grids scroller? Again thanks for the help.

Comment: @metalideath: You might want `#tabs-1 {overflow: hidden !important}` and then tell the grid widget to scroll within that space. I've never used that grid widget so I don't know how it handles scrolling, sorry.

Comment: I ended up getting it to work with the scrolling like I wanted. http://jsfiddle.net/SQu6K/20/ Thanks for the help.